# Behavior of the spectral radius of $A_1^k\ldots A_j^k$ when $k\to \infty$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, limits, perturbation-theory

**First formulation of my problem :**

Let $A_1,\cdots,A_j$ be hermitian **definite** positive matrices of dimension $n$ with all their eigenvalues in $(0;1]$. We also add the condition that $\|A_1\cdots A_j\|_2^2<1$. I am wondering if the quantity

$$\frac{-1}{k}\log\left(\rho\left(A_1^k\cdots A_j^k\right)\right)$$

has a (positive and finite) limit when $k$ goes to infinity. Here $\rho(M)$ denote the spectral radius of the matrix $M$.

**Second formulation :**

The same problem can be reformulated in terms of ordinary differential equation : let $a : [0;1]\to \mathscr H_n^{+}$ be a bounded, piecewise continuous function from $[0;1]$ to the space of hermitian **semi** definite positive matrices and define $G_a :[0;1]\to \mathscr{M}_n(\mathbf C)$ as the solution of the following differential equation

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{rcl}
G_a(0)&=&\mathrm{Id}\\
G_a'(t)&=&-a(t)G(t).
\end{array}
\right.
$$
We moreover assume that $\|G_a(1)\|_2^2<1$. I want to know if the quantity 
$$\frac{-1}{k}\log\big(\rho\left(G_{ka}(1)\right)\big)$$
has a finite positive limit when $k\to \infty$. This is indeed a reformulation of the first problem if we take $a$ to be piecewise constant on every interval $[\frac{i-1}{j};\frac{i}{j})$ and such that $\exp(-a(i-1)/j)=A_i$. By an argument of density the two problems are equivalent.

**What I already know :**
Note that in dimension $1$ (*ie* the matrices are just real numbers) the answer to my question is trivially yes. The few numerical simulations i have done (and my intuition) seems to indicate that the answer to my question is yes : there is a positive finite limit. Finally, i was able to prove an upper and a lower bound for the first formulation of the problem, these bounds are not sharp and i will only sketch the proof of the bounds :

*first bound :* All the $A_i^k$ are contractions of $\mathbf C^n$ so $\rho\left(A_1^k\cdots A_j^k\right)<1$ and thus $\det\left(A_1^k\cdots A_j^k\right)<1$ but $\det\left(A_1^k\cdots A_j^k\right)=\det\left(A_1\cdots A_j\right)^k$ and thus $\rho\left(A_1^k\cdots A_j^k\right)\geq \det\left(A_1\cdots A_j\right)^{k}$, giving us the first bound.

*second bound :* One can show that all the coefficients of $A_1^k$ are of the form $C(\alpha+o(1))^k$ for some $C$ and $\alpha$. The product and the sum of two of this expressions can still be exprimed in that way. From that we deduce that the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial of $A_1^k\cdots A_j^k$ are also of the form $C(\alpha+o(1))^k$, so it's an exponentially small perturbation of the polynomial $X^n$. Since the roots of a polynomial (of degree $n$) are $1/n$-Hölder functions of the coefficients we get the other bound on $\rho\left(A_1\cdots A_j\right)^k$.

This second bound suggest to concider the matrices $A_1^k\cdots A_j^k$ as small perturbations of the null matrix, maybe this approach is fruitfull but i don't know much about perturbation theory.

Comment: So $\rho(A)\leq\Vert A\Vert$, and the operator norm is submultiplicative, so can we not say that: $\rho(A_1^k...A_j^k)\leq \Vert A_1^k... A_j^k\Vert\leq \Vert A_1\Vert^k...\Vert A_j\Vert^k$. Then taking the log, this becomes $-\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^j\log(\Vert A_i\Vert^k)=-\sum_{i=1}^j\log(\Vert A_i\Vert)$, which is definitely finite and positive by the conditions on each $A_i$.

Comment: Yes this is a good looking (and simpler) upper bound, thank you. But alas it is not a limit.

Comment: Ah, even though it's an upper bound, the sequence still might not converge since the sequence might not be increasing.

Comment: Oh shoot, and I was careless with the inequalities and it's a lower bound anyway.

Comment: In fact your bound doesn't work because one could possibly have $\|A_i\|=1$ for  every $i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any $n\times n$ Hermitian matrix $B$ has $n$ real eigenvalues $\lambda_j$ and $n$ eigenvectors $u_j$ such that

$$\lambda_j u_j=Bu_j.$$

We can choose the eigenvectors such that $\Vert u_j\Vert_2=1$ or that they are an orthonormal base. We define the matrix

$$X:=\begin{pmatrix}
u_1 \\
\vdots \\
u_n
\end{pmatrix}$$

with the row vectors $u_j$ such that it is a unitary complex matrix.  Then there exists a decomposition

$$B=\overline X^t \Lambda X$$

with the diagonal matrix $\Lambda=(\lambda_j)$ and the conjugate transpose $\overline X^t$ of the matrix $X$. Moreover this conjugate transpose is the inverse of the matrix X or

$$E=\overline X^t X =X\overline X^t$$

with the identity matrix $E$. Now we easily obtain

$$B^2={(\overline X^t \Lambda X)\cdot(\overline X^t \Lambda X)}={\overline X^t \Lambda X\overline X^t \Lambda X}={\overline X^t \Lambda\Lambda X}={\overline X^t \Lambda^2 X}$$

and in general

$$B^2={\overline X^t \Lambda^k X}.$$

But we immediately obtain $\Lambda^k=(\lambda_j^k)$.

With these notations we define

$$A_i=\overline X_i^t \Lambda_i X_i$$

with the eigenvalues $\lambda_{ij}$ and the eigenvectors $u_{ij}$. We immediately get

$$\tag{1}R_k:=A_1^k A_2^k \cdots A_i^k={(\overline X_1^t \Lambda_1^k X_1)\cdot (\overline X_2^t \Lambda_2^k X_2)\cdots(\overline X_i^t \Lambda_i^k X_i)}.$$

In this product we replace the eigenvalues $\lambda_{ij}^k$ with the variables $\xi_{ij}=\lambda_{ij}^k$ and obtain $\Lambda_i^k=(\xi_{ij}).$

Now we simply multiply out the matrices (1) and the resulting matrix $R_k$ can be written as

$$R_k=(r_{\mu\nu})=(r_{\mu\nu}((\xi_{ij})_{i\times n})=(r_{\mu\nu}(\xi_{11},\dots\xi_{1n},\dots,\xi_{i1},\dots\xi_{in}))$$

so that every coefficient $r_{\mu\nu}$ is a polynomial in the $(\xi_{ij})_{i\times n}$. There must be a monomial $\xi_{1s_1}\xi_{2s_2}\cdots\xi_{is_i}=(\lambda_{1s_1}\lambda_{2s_2}\cdots\lambda_{is_i})^k$ such that  $\lambda_{max}:=\vert\lambda_{1s_1}\lambda_{2s_2}\cdots\lambda_{is_i}\vert$ is maximal for a certain choice $1\le s_\nu\le n$ and at least one coefficient

$$\dfrac{r_{\mu\nu}}{\lambda_{max}^k}$$

is unequal to $0$. Otherwise the matrix $R_k$ is $0$ and nothing is left to do. We finally define

$$\hat R_k:=\dfrac{1}{\lambda_{max}^k}R_k.$$

With $k\to\infty$  the matrix $\hat R_\infty$ is a matrix with complex coefficients in which all monomials of the matrix $R_k$ with a value $\vert\lambda_{1s_1}\lambda_{2s_2}\cdots\lambda_{is_i}\vert\lt\lambda_{max}$ are zero and only the monomials with the absolute value $\lambda_{max}$ are left. The division of these monomials through $\lambda_{max}^k$ leads to a complex value for each coefficient $\hat r_{\mu\nu}$. It is well known from functional analysis that the spectrum $Spec\{\hat R_k\}$ of the matrices $\hat R_k$ converges to the spectrum $Spec\{\hat R_\infty\}$ (see for example [MathOverflow:Convergence of eigenvectors](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59413/convergence-of-eigenvectors)). The maximal absolute eigenvalue $s_{max}$ of this spectrum is finite and the spectral radius $\rho(\hat R_k)=\lim_{m\to\infty}\sqrt[m]{\left\Vert \hat R_k^m\right\Vert}$. In the case $s_{max}>0$ we obtain

$$\tag{2}\lim_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[k]{\rho(R_k)}=\lim_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[k]{\rho( \lambda_{max}^k\hat R_k)}\to\lim_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[k]{\lambda_{max}^k\cdot s_{max}}=\lambda_{max}$$

so that the limit exists and it is a product of spectral values $\vert\lambda_{1s_1}\lambda_{2s_2}\cdots\lambda_{is_i}\vert$ for a certain choice of an eigenvalue $\lambda_{is_i}$ of each matrix $A_i$.

In the case that $s_{max}=0$ we have to dig a little deeper. In this case we determine the characteristic polynomial

$$p_k(\lambda):=\lambda^n+a_{n-1}\lambda^{n-1}+\dots+a_0:=det(\lambda E-\hat R_k)$$

of the Matrix $\hat R_k$. If all coefficients $a_j$ are zero we take $s_{max}=0$. Otherwise the coefficients $a_j$ converge to $0$ with growing k and there exists an $\alpha\gt0$ such that the polynomials

$$\hat p_k(\lambda)=\alpha^{nk}p_k\left(\dfrac{\lambda}{\alpha^k}\right)=\lambda^n+a_{n-1}\alpha^{k}\lambda^{n-1}+\dots+\alpha^{nk}a_0$$

converge to a polynomial $\hat p_\infty(\lambda)$ with bounded coefficients and at least one coefficient is unequal to $0$. But then the polynomials $\hat p_k(\lambda)$ converge to a maximal zero $\lambda_0\ne0$ and we take $s_{max}=\vert\lambda_0\vert\alpha^{-k}$ in the limit (2).

Comment: But how do you know $s_{max}$ is not $0$ ? For example with $R_k=\begin{pmatrix}1/4^k & 1/4^k \\ 1/2^k & 1/4^k\end{pmatrix}$ we have $\lambda_{max}=1/2$ and $s_{max}=0$. Also the product of hermitian positive definite matrices is not hermitian in general so $\|R_k\|_2\neq \rho(R_k)$. In my previous example $s_{max}=0$ but $\rho(R_k)^{1/k}$ does converges to something positive and finite. However i agree that when $s_{max}>0$ this methods leads to what we want.

Comment: Of course I should have taken the radius of convergence instead of the norm and in the case $s_{max}\ne 0$ this does not change anything as you noticed. In my edit I dealt with the case $s_{max}=0$.

Comment: Very good ! This seems correct to me, I even think you can use your technique for the case $s_{max}=0$ directly on the caracteristic polynomial of $R_k$ and get the result quicker.  I'll think a little bit more about it just to be sure and then i'll award the bounty.